# Quit function in python programming

Tags: python, runtime-error

I have tried to use the 'quit()' function in python and the spyder's compiler keep says me "quit" is not defined

```py
print("Welcome to my computer quiz")

playing = input("Do you want to play? ")

if (playing != "yes" ):
    quit()
    
print("Okay! Let's play :)")
```

the output keep says me "name 'quit' is not defined", how can i solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invert the logic and play if the user answers *yes*. The game will automatically quit when it reaches the end of the file

```py
print("Welcome to my computer quiz")

playing = input("Do you want to play? ")

if (playing == "yes" ):
    print("Okay! Let's play :)")
```

Comment: it was the beginning of the program and i want to quit of the program when the users says anything else than yes. That's my problem. How can i solve it?

Comment: @ŞevketÖLMEZ with the code I gave you. Run it and see that it does what you want.

Comment: Yes but i am gonna build a program with millions of line of code so i dont want to build all of them below the if function. But thank you!! I will remember that if i have a problem like that

Comment: That's where classes come into play... But feel free to use `sys.exit()`

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as `quit()` in python. Python rather has `exit()`. Simply replace your `quit()` to `exit()`.

```
print("Welcome to my computer quiz")

playing = input("Do you want to play? ")

if (playing != "yes" ):
    exit()
    
print("Okay! Let's play :)")
```

Comment: I was watching a youtube video and he built a program in this way and it ran without a problem in visual studio. But i learnt the solve of that problem. So thank you so much for your help